# How to Compute the mean of a uniform random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

How to Compute the mean of a uniform random variable at $(-1,1)$ using the moment generator function?

I did the procedure but I obtein $0$ and I don't know why happend this or if it is right

Comment: You got the correct answer. Are you asking for someone to check your work? In that case you should show the steps you took.

Answer (score 1):

The density function is
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2},\ -1<x<1.$$
The moment-generating function is
\begin{align*}M(t)&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{tx}f(x)dx\\&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}e^{tx}dx\\
&=\begin{cases}\dfrac{1}{2t}\left[e^{tx}\right]_{-1}^{1}=\dfrac{e^t-e^{-t}}{2t}&t\neq 0\\
1&t=0\end{cases}.\end{align*}
Now, derivate $M$ at $0$ using one-sided limits and get the result.

Comment: A nitpick: It is not necessary to compute the moment generating function, only to differentiate it.

Comment: Not a nitpick but a nice trick!